# How to solve error of R.menu

Tags: android, menu

I've searched about its solution all over the top websites in google but I can't find a right solution.

Means everyone talks about that there may be a missing **menu.xml or problem with R** but i want exact solution for this problem because I'm new to android.

```
public class CallState extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_call_state);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)         
getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Is Ringing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Currently in A Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone is Available for Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    };
    telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

}
  @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.CallState,menu);
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: did you check you have the menu as you mentioned in your resource

Comment: no, i've created my own menu.xml sir.

Comment: what is the name of the menu?

Comment: If you want help to resolve an error, you should tell us what the error actually is.

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't get your question sir.

Comment: @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.**menu**.CallState,menu);
        return true;
      }

*Error:* Could not resolve **menu** .

Comment: what is CallState?? you need to put your menu.xml there..

Answer (score 0):

you use `R.menu.main` so your program will find in the **`res/menu` folder** for `main.xml`.

So all you need is to create a new file `main.xml` in **res/menu**. And don't import `android.R` to your class.

rebuild your project and that should be working

Answer (score 0):

1 .Go to import and check your R is accurately places with your package Name.
2 . your class package name matches with project package name.

Most of times this problem happened when u copy and paste a class from another project and the class Package Name is different from Your project Package Name.